# Laravel multiple joins?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to take out admin username by leftJoin. 
I have a table called **server_bans_history** and **users**.

server_bans_history table have a unique row called **steamid** and **admin_steamid**

taking all data by:

```
@foreach ($user->BanHistory as $BanHistory)
```

This code works fine, but i dont know hot got admin_steamid row and i need convert that steamid to username from users table.

Becouse now if i use `{{ $BanHistory->username }}` i'm getting BANNED user USERNAME not ADMIN username.

Example now i'm using code:

```
$user->BanHistory = DB::table('server_bans_history AS sh')
->leftJoin('users AS us', 'us.steam_id', '=', 'sh.steamid')
->where('sh.steamid', '=', $user->steam_id)
->select("sh.*", "us.*")
->orderBy('sh.date', 'desc')
->get('');
```

I need to convert admin_steamid -> user.username

Can i do with multiple leftJoin or something like that?

Thanks for helping me uderstand leftJoin!

Comment: Why don't you just use Eloquent Relationships, which will handle all of this for you, instead of having to write a lot of heavy join operations? Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thanks for answer @OleHaugset, but i need first understand how works with multiple leftJoin :)

Comment: Updated my post to better understading what i need :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be it:

```
$user->BanHistory = DB::table('server_bans_history AS sh')
->leftJoin('users AS us', 'us.steam_id', '=', 'sh.steamid')
->leftJoin('users AS us2', 'us.steam_id', '=', 'sh.admin_steamid')
->where('sh.steamid', '=', $user->steam_id)
->select("sh.*", "us.*", "us2.username as admin_name")
->orderBy('sh.date', 'desc')
->get('');
```

Comment: I'm getting banned user username not admin username by using your example. I think i need do somethink like: `->where('sh.admin_steamid', '=', $user->steam_id)` but i dont know how can i use 2 where with the same table row name :)

Comment: Is admin_steamid the id of an admin who banned the user?